# Hot to get the Health of an environment using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am updating ebs environment using cli using the command "elasticbeanstalk update-environment", After this command i want to get the Health status of the environment (If I login to aws console/website I can see the status )

[image]

**How to get this health status using cli**

I have tried [describe-instances-health](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/describe-instances-health.html) But it is giving some error

"**An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the DescribeInstancesHealth operation: DescribeInstancesHealth is not supported.**"

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? Neither `describe-instances-health` nor `describe-environment-health` are working for me. They both give me the same **InvalidRequestException** as you got.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `describe-environment-health` not `describe-instances-health`.

This is the structure of the command

```
describe-environment-health
[--environment-name <value>]
[--environment-id <value>]
[--attribute-names <value>]
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

Taken from [AWS official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/describe-environment-health.html).